# Spark Streaming - Cached table registered in memory created from each RDD of a windowed stream

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using spark 1.5.2, my application has StreamingContext created on files and runs a windowed operation with 30 sec window and 10 sec slide interval.
I use foreachRDD for converting each RDD obtained from windowstream to a dataframe and further registered it as table using registerTempTable with name "T_Subs_Rev".

On running the application, spark GUI shows, "T_Subs_Rev" getting created again and again on each sliding interval(when using CACHE TABLE). And entry keeps on adding for each new table created with its respective size in memory.

Q1) Want to know as table name is same "T_Subs_Rev", what is actually happening.. will new entry will replace the older table in memory? Or still all tables with same name keeps on created in the memory.

Q2) Can we control how long a table can be cached in the memory, like with some time parameter and without having to explicitly call UNCACHE.

Comment: Hey @kansingh,  did you get answer to this question? I have a similar situation, and my cache is growing very large.